# Equalizer design under Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to do manually an spectrum sound with Illustrator :

[image]

What can I use ? Pencil ? Brush ? If yes what sort ? Thank you

PS : I have a wacom tablet

My bad result :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried some techniques? Your question is more likely to get answers if you can provide some additional information. Especially if you can show us what you have tried and why you didn't like the results.

Comment: @leugim I try with a paint brush, I update my post with my result

Answer (score 1):

### Draw the spectrum line

There are a few effects in illustrator you can use for this.
Look in the `Effects` menu for:

- `Stylize -> Scribble`
- `Distort & Transform -> Roughen`
- `Distort & Transform -> Zig-zag`

You will have to play a bit with scale and each of the settings. Sometimes the results are very different if you draw a short or a long line.

The `Scribble` effect looks very promising. I would avoid values that make the line "loop" or go "back" on itself. The real sound diagrams don't do this.
You will get better results with your digitizer/tablet! The trick is to understand the basic properties of these diagrams.

### Line styling

After you've got some lines you like, you can `Expand Appearance` to get a line with editable anchor points.
Play around with different types of brushes. Most of the brushes have settings like scale and spacing, that will help you avoid sharp edges.
**Bristle brushes** offer a lot of options and should get you there.

Another thing to look out for is the mitter limit on strokes or - [Why stroke angles in Illustrator do not behave equally?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/19783/682)

[image: Too low mitter limit create cut-offs on corners]