# Why does Affinity Designer stroke not match the object?

Tags: stroke, affinity-designer

If you look at the upper left of the `N` you can see the outline matches the object perfectly. But on the upper right side the outline is diagonal to the sharp corner, but I want it just like the left side.

I tried the other settings but they make it a lot worse, so is there a way to fix the stroke or is it easier to copy the elements and make them bigger?

[image: Example Image]
[image: properties]

Comment: what happens if you change the Miter value?

Comment: Yes that worked. If you want you can write an answer and I will accept it. @Luciano

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why stroke angles in Illustrator do not behave equally?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19783/why-stroke-angles-in-illustrator-do-not-behave-equally)

Comment: @Luciano Is this really a duplicate of the question? Because the other question is about illustrator.

Comment: I know. But it is actually the same problem, with the same solution; miter is a common concept used in vector software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your corner doesn't match the shape is because your Miter Limit is too low. If the angle of the corner falls below the limit, the corner is butted rather than mitered.

Set it to a higher value and it will follow the shape more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Align the stroke fully inside the shape and make the shape bigger.